# Run program as "standard user" with administrator privileges

Tags: permissions, sudo, chown

I have a program that I can only run as root (because it uses some hardware I have no access to as simple user).
It creates files & folders as user/group root:root, and I would like to be able to make it generate these files with my standard user's ownership rights.

Currently, I chown them every time, but it is very redundant & frustrating... :/

Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: What kind of hardware, and used how? if it's managed by udev, then probably the best solution is to write a udev rule to give the device appropriate permissions (such as group ownership by a group to which you can add your non-privileged user)

Comment: You can create a wrapper script, that would call your program first and then chown produced files, and call that script instead of origin program.

Comment: Better idea may be to save list of files and directories in a file and give this file as input to chown using `<`.